# Angular 12 NgOnChanges Cannot Read Property of null

Tags: angular

I have a child component that is reading the changes of a selection from a drop down list.  I'm trying to set local variables on the component based on when the selection changes and it works unless I clear out the selection, then I get:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'carrierStatusId')

The code:

```
public carrierCorporateStatusEnum = CarrierCorporateApprovalStatus;
public carrierStatusEnum = CarrierStatus;
public carrierAddendumStatusEnum = CarrierAddendumStatus;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

if (changes.carrier.currentValue != changes.carrier.previousValue )
{
  this.carrier = changes.carrier.currentValue;
  this.corporateStatus = changes.corporateStatus.currentValue;
  this.carrierStatus = changes.carrier.currentValue.carrierStatusId;
  this.carrierAddendumStatus = changes.carrier.currentValue.addendumStatus;
}
```

}

I know there's a way to check for null but I can't quite figure it out.  Think I'm making this harder than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.carrierStatus = changes.carrier.currentValue?.carrierStatusId;
```

Add the "?" before .carrierStatusId.

But take care that `this.carrierStatus` will be null.

Comment: I think that was the one place I didn't add the null check, it's early, thank you!